# Check for NoneTypes in a list of iterables

Tags: python, typeerror, iterable, nonetype, try-except

I would like to loop over a list of iterables, but with the requirement that some elements could be of type `None`.

This could look something like this:

```py
none_list = [None, [0, 1]]

for x, y in none_list:
    print("I'm not gonna print anything!")
```

However, this will prompt `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

Currently, I catch the error and deal with the `NoneType` afterwards. For my use case, this results in a lot of duplicated code as I basically substitute the `None` values and do the same as initially planned inside the for-loop.

```py
try:
    for x, y in none_list:
        print("I'm not gonna print anything!")
except TypeError:
    print("But I will!")
    # Deal with NoneType here
```

**Question:**
What‘s the best way to ignore the `TypeError` and check for `None` values inside the initial loop?

Comment: How do you want to deal with the `None`s? Do you just want to ignore them? In that case, you can use `filter`.

Comment: @PaulM. I would like to substitute the `None`s inside the loop with custom values (_such as_  `-1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over each item and check for `None`:

```
none_list = [None, [0, 1]]
for item in none_list:
    if item is None:
        continue
    x, y = item
    print(x, y)
```

Or you may use list comprehension to eliminate `None`s first, then you can iterate over normally:

```
list_without_none = [item for item in none_list if item is not None]
for x, y in list_without_none:
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option is exactly what I want to do! Somehow didn't think about iterating over a single `item` instead of the individual elements.

Comment: Yeah, you can try `x, y = None` and get the same error but if you do `x = None` it will run without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

I actually find `filter` quite handy for this:

```
for x,y in filter(None, none_list):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: I like the approach, it's very clean! I want to be able to deal with the `None`s afterwards though, so I accepted the other answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Note that this will filter all *falsy* values: `>>> list(filter(None, ["", 0, False, None, 3])) -> [3]`